# Cannot add border radius in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a border radius property when click on a div but it does not work:

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
    Div 1        
</div>

<br>

<div class="div2">
    Div 2            
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".div2").click(function() {
    $(this).css({"border-radius":"10px 15px 20px 25px;"})
});
```

My jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6mLpJ/

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the semi-colon inside the value that assigned to your `border-radius` property:

```
$(this).css({"border-radius":"10px 15px 20px 25px;"})
------------------------------------------- here ^ -----
```

`;` used to seperate the style between elements in CSS. It's not part of the value so you just need to remove it to make your function works.

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6mLpJ/2/

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra semicolon there in your css properties which is not needed at all.. remove that and it should work..

```
 $(this).css({"border-radius":"10px 15px 20px 25px"})
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6mLpJ/3/)

Comment: samething already given in answer :) why repeating same answer??

Comment: i think when i was working on the fiddle ,user1479606  aleardy answered this.. i gave him the upvote (btw).... after i posted my answer and saw the answer was already there.. :) :)

Comment: yeah I agree that happens often :) +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This simpler method might also help:

```
$(".div2").click(function() {
    $(this).css('border-radius','10px 15px 20px 25px');
}
```